# How much data does SQL Server 2008 can handle?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the threshold of number of registries and fields SQL Server can tolerate?  In other words, how many rows and columns can be handled?

Comment: It should be able to handle all of the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much data (it's about size of data, not number of rows) it can handle depends on what edition. You can find details here: [Maximum Capacity Specification for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

When it comes to the number of rows, available storage should be the only limit.

Answer (score 3):

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

Short answer, however many can fit in the storage medium.

Answer (score 1):

Until you run out of storage with up to 30k columns per table.

The average database is Mickey Mouse no matter how big you think it is...